# How to tell Applescript to call a Fondation's class's init?

Tags: applescript, script, error, time, swift

A subquestion could be: how to find the AppleScript name of a class's instances?

Context: I use the following to access NSTimeZone variables and apply methods.

```
use scripting additions -- essential to use (current date) with framework "Foundation"
use framework "Foundation"
    
tell class "NSTimeZone" of current application to resetSystemTimeZone()
    
set aTZ to current application's NSTimeZone
set localZone to aTZ's localTimeZone()
set defaultZone to aTZ's defaultTimeZone()
set aDate to (current date)
    
defaultZone's |name|() as string
defaultZone's abbreviation as string
defaultZone's abbreviationForDate:aDate
defaultZone's daylightSavingTimeOffsetForDate:aDate
defaultZone's secondsFromGMT()
defaultZone's secondsFromGMTForDate:aDate
```

etc.

In Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimezone), the last line above intended for SWIFT describes the use like this:
func secondsFromGMT(for aDate: Date) -> Int

It was hard to find the correct formulation for Applescript (secondsFromGMTForDate:aDate) but I figured it out. What I cannot conceive though is how to call an initializer like these ones described for SWIFT:

```
init?(name tzName: String)  
convenience init(forSecondsFromGMT seconds: Int)
```

Based on the previous pattern I tried all kind of formulations like these:

```
defaultZone's initWithName:"America/Toronto"  
tell defaultZone to initName:"EST"  
tell defaultZone to initNameString:"EST"  
tell defaultZone to initTzName:"EST"  
tell class NSTimeZone of current application to set SecondsFromGMT to 3600  
tell defaultZone to initforSecondsFromGMT:3600   
tell defaultZone to init:forSecondsFromGMT  
defaultZone's initNameString("EST")
```

...and many other variations. I always get an error like this:

```
error "-[_NSSwiftTimeZone initWithName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc514913750" number -10000
```

In fact I get the same error even if I write something like

```
tell defaultZone to playPiano:"EST"
```

so I get it that I don't have the right name (selector) for the call. And maybe not the right way to call either. On top of that, case matters in the names.

What is the correct way to do it? Is there a way to list the instances, variables, methods, functions of an NS class as they are referred to in Applescript?

Comment: It might be easier to use Swift as a scripting language. Scripts with `#!/usr/bin/swift` as the first line will run in the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppleScript isn't set up to use Swift or its documentation.  Setting Apple's documentation language to Objective-C is the way to go, since that is what the AppleScriptObjC bridge uses.  From there, the conversion to AppleScript is fairly consistent.

The `defaultTimeZone` is a property of the class that can be set to a time zone to use if you don't want to use the `localTimeZone`.  As you found out, your error messages are saying that it can't be used with that particular method (selector).

The documentation lists the various properties and methods for the particular class and the class that it inherits from. There are some convenience class methods that return an object, for example `timeZoneWithName`, but the various `init` methods need to be used with an `alloc` method to get a new instance, for example:

```
set defaultZone to current application's NSTimeZone's alloc's initWithName:"America/Toronto"
-- or --
set defaultZone to current application's NSTimeZone's timeZoneWithName:"America/Toronto"
```

Comment: Fantastic. That's all I needed, both solutions work perfectly. And thanks for pointing to the use of the Objective-C documentation instead of SWIFT's.